# ASP.NET Core Validate float range issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, unobtrusive-validation

I have this property

```
    [Required]
    [Range(0, float.MaxValue)]
    [Display(Name = "Tolerância Inferior")]
    public float ToleranciaInferior { get; set; }
```

Using jquery validation when i type a float like 22,1 it gives me this error

> The field Tolerância Inferior must be between 0 and
>   3,40282346638529E+38.

I just want my floats to be positive values. How can i achieve this?

Comment: Your browser is probably using a locale which uses `.` for the decimal point. If you try to enter `22.1` instead of `22,1` does it work?

Comment: this is not the problem because i have overriden jquery validation to accept only commas

Comment: but then it should just work. If you check in the developer tools' networking tab, how is the data transmitted to the server? Does it have a comma or a dot?

Comment: try [Range(1, float.MaxValue)]

Comment: the problem is not about comma or dot 'cause this works if i remove when range. it's then the numeric place is higehr than 3